# Selenium wont find text values for dropdown

Tags: jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, sumoselect.js

I am creating a test to check the values of the dropdownlist but when ever i call

```
new SelectElement(Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table[@id='tblListUserSearch']/tbody/tr/td[5]/div/select")));
```

It picks up the dropdown list and all the items withing the DDL but when trying to get the options text its always blank/null.

I am also using [SumoSelect](https://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/) Jquery plugin for this dropdown. If i was to stop using this the line above removes the 'div' before 'select' and seems to work.

Am i missing something or could it just be that Selenium doesn't like the JQuery pluggin???

EDIT
Here is my code for the beginning of the test

```
Selenium.Open("/ListUserStatus.aspx");
Selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");
Thread.Sleep(2000);
var mySelect = new SelectElement(Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table[@id='tblListUserSearch']/tbody/tr/td[5]/div/select")));
var options = mySelect.Options;
```

EDIT 19/11/2015
Here is my HTML being created

```
<td style="padding: 3px;">

                        <div class="SumoSelect" tabindex="0"><select style="display: none;" id="testCase" class="SlectBox dropDown clearDropDown" multiple="multiple" data-bind="selectedOptions: selectedPage ">
                        <!-- ko foreach: PageAccess -->
                        <!-- ko if: $root.getPriviledges($data) != false -->
                        <option value="25" data-bind="text: $data.PageAccess, value: $data.PageAccessID">SPID Search</option>
                        <!-- /ko -->

                        <!-- ko if: $root.getPriviledges($data) != false -->
                        <option value="37" data-bind="text: $data.PageAccess, value: $data.PageAccessID">Submit Transaction</option>
                        <!-- /ko -->

                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </select><p class="CaptionCont SlectBox"><span class="placeholder">Please Select...</span><label><i></i></label></p><div class="optWrapper multiple"><p class="select-all"><span><i></i></span><label>Select All</label></p><ul class="options"><li data-val="25"><span><i></i></span><label>SPID Search</label></li><li data-val="37"><span><i></i></span><label>Submit Transaction</label></li></ul><div class="MultiControls"><p class="btnOk">OK</p><p class="btnCancel">Cancel</p></div></div></div>


                </td>
```

As you can see i am also using Knockout.JS to bind the data for the dropdown. After this i have a short JS script to apply SumoSelect to the drop-down. Script below

```
$('.dropDown').each(function () {
            $(this).SumoSelect(
            {
                placeholder: 'Please Select...',
                selectAll: true

            });
        });
```

Once this script is applied it creates the DIV `<div class="SumoSelect" tabindex="0">`. This is what seems to be causing the problem as when using selenium it doesn't seem to be visible to the WebDrivers.

SIDE NOTE
When using the Selenium plugin for Firefox and recording my steps and replaying them, it is able to find the DDL and click yet when coding the test it doesnt like it at all

Comment: Can you please post the HTML code or link? so we can help you

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how your website code looks like but I managed to get text from dropdown options as follows:

```
IWebElement TestDropDown = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table[@id='tblListUserSearch']/tbody/tr/td[5]/div/select"));
string[] seperator = {"\n", "\r"};
string dropdownText = TestDropDown.Text;
string[] dropdownOptions = dropdownText.Split(seperator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with dropdown menu which has implemented with jquery plug-in. Hope this can helps you.
`final Select droplist = new Select(driver.findElement(By
                        .xpath("xpath-expression")));
                List<WebElement> oSize = droplist.getOptions();
                int iListSize = oSize.size();
                System.out.println("No.of list size is ......" + iListSize);
                for (int i = 0; i < iListSize; i++) {
                    System.out.println("i value is..." + i);
                    droplist.selectByIndex(i);
                    String sValue = droplist.getOptions().get(i).getText();
                    System.out.println(sValue);`

Answer (score 0):

This code might help:

```
 WebElement getdropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("your_id"));
 Select select = new Select(getdropdown);
 select.selectByIndex(1);    
 WebElement web2 = select.getFirstSelectedOption();
 getdropdown.sendKeys(web2.getText());
```